# How should I use backup to restore the previous version of my website

Tags: joomla-3.x, administration, akeebabackup, backups

I have a website's Backup which I had made about three months ago. This is a Joomla 3.2 version backup made with the Extension Akeeba Backup.

My Question is how can I restore this when my current Joomla stable website is of version 3.3?

I searched it over internet but could not find any good links.
Please give some steps which would give me an idea of this process.

Comment: https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/quick-start-guide/restoring-backups.html

Comment: Has something happened to your current site? If not, take a backup of your current Joomla 3.3 site and use that for any restores you need to make.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Please try to explain better what is your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your current site is damaged but you don't want to lose any data, then you've got a long road ahead of you. You really need to provide more detail as to what you want to accomplish.

That said, if you just need to restore the old one and then upgrade it, use Akeeba Kickstart on your server to restore the backup.

1. Move your live site into a subfolder
2. Copy the .jpa file from the old backup into your top level of your site
3. Upload akeeba kickstart. You really only need the kickstart.php file, the jquery and json files and the language file for the language you're using. [You can get it here.](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download.html)
4. Run kickstart and restore your site-BUT...
5. If you don't want to lose the 3.3 database, create a new database and restore the backup into a new db instead of replacing the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Use Akeeba Kickstart:
https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html

1. Create new database in cPanel
2. Upload kickstart.php to where you want to restore site.
3. Go to URL (http://www.mywebsite.com/kickstart.php) and follow the prompts

Answer (score 1):

If the backup is 3 months old then you are going to lose 3 months of data, a "backup" is basically a snapshot of the site at the time it was made, typically weekly backups are a norm because in the worst case you have lost 1 week worth of data. Daily are the best but can be costly in server space to keep enough of them to be "safe".

So YellowWebMonkey goes into using Akeeba kickstart, that will restore the site to that backup but you will lose everything else in the last 3 months, this is the only option to "restore" if that is the only backup you have.

If you have any sort of programming background or know someone who does you can "fix" the current site to get it working again, then speed up your backup rate to prevent a situation like this coming up again. This can be a lot of work but in some cases is the best option.

If you clarify on what is wrong with the current site, there is a possibility we can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You should restore your back up to a new database and location, then use Akeeba Site Diff to merge changes between the two sites so you don't lose any outdated data.

https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-sitediff.html